# In memory text search using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, full-text-search

I have a couple megs of text in memory stored in a 2-D array, where the first column is the line number and the second column is the text itself.
What I would like to do is find an existing solution where I could pass this sort of data structure (It's malleable) and a Boolean search query ideally with wildcards, and figure out which rows contain matches.
Are there any APIs out there that do this? I don't want to use something like Lucene because I don't want to bother building an index. I basically want to enumerate through a collection of strings and return those that have hits against the query passed in.

Comment: `forech` or LINQ + RegEx?

Comment: What is the line number used for? Would it be fine if you ordered the list and did a binary search?

Comment: @Simon -- yes, ordered and binary would be ok

Comment: 2MB is not that big... you problably don't need anything special, unless you need to query it in a tight loop

Comment: @Matt, please comment on what's wrong with LINQ+RegEx suggestion?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov nothing inhearently, but I wanted to pass in boolean expressions

Comment: @Matt Linq's `Where` takes in a boolean expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're loading the data, searching it once, and then throwing it away, you're better off going the LINQ+RegEx route as suggested in the comments above. That is, you might as well do your search on the first pass through the data instead of making a pass to index the data then searching the index as a search engine would do.

But if you're going to load the data once and then repeatedly search it, then you're better off using a search engine. If you still don't want to use Lucene.Net, an in-memory [System.Data.Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) database with full-text search would work well, too.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be useful to store them in SQL server and use the methodology described in this document?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: -1 OP specifically asks for an in-memory solution, presumably to be for client side.